# How to drag an average result in MySQL till new values are added?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a table with sales and sales-average.

Every row must be a natural day, so week-ends are going to show no sales.
As I am aware about the fact of avoiding week-ends to calculate the sales-average, I use two queries and link the results.

Everything runs smooth except for the fact that I would like the query to keep the last sales-average value in weekends, as shown below with last year' february sales:

```
What I get:           What I would like:

day   sales     avg   day   sales     avg
-------------------   -------------------
28   57,544  52,289   28   57,544  52,289
27   24,585  52,013   27   24,585  52,013
26        0       0   26        0  53,537    
25        0       0   25        0  53,537    
24   64,494  53,537   24   64,494  53,537
23   41,593  52,892   23   41,593  52,892
22  119,473  53,598   22  119,473  53,598
21   61,368  49,207   21   61,368  49,207
20   22,739  48,338   20   22,739  48,338
19        0       0   19        0  50,307    
18        0       0   18        0  50,307    
17   60,764  50,307   17   60,764  50,307
16   28,227  49,436   16   28,227  49,436
15   47,697  51,364   15   47,697  51,364
14   21,423  51,730   14   21,423  51,730
13  119,182  55,098   13  119,182  55,098
12        0       0   12        0  47,087    
11        0       0   11        0  47,087    
10   26,382  47,087   10   26,382  47,087
 9   62,140  50,045    9   62,140  50,045
 8   76,742  48,029    8   76,742  48,029
 7   90,080  42,287    7   90,080  42,287
 6   27,865  30,339    6   27,865  30,339
 5        0       0    5        0  31,163
 4        0       0    4        0  31,163
 3   26,577  31,163    3   26,577  31,163
 2   50,259  33,456    2   50,259  33,456
 1   16,653  16,653    1   16,653  16,653
-------------------   -------------------
```

This is a sample of my code:

```
select q0.day,
q1.net,
q2.med
from
(
select day(date) as day
from dates
order by date desc
) as q0
left join
(
select day(date) as day,
▸   sum(sales) as net
▸   from file
▸   group by date
) as q1
on q0.day=q1.day
left join
(
select day(q20.date) as day,
avg(q21.neto) as med
from
▸   (select date
▸   from file
▸   group by date
▸   ) as q20,
▸   (select date,
▸   sum(sales) as net
▸   from file
▸   group by date
▸   ) as q21
where q20.date >= q21.date
group by q20.date
) as q2
on q0.day=q2.day
```

Thanks,

Comment: If you're happy with that monster query then consider handling what is after all a display problem at the application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT D.day AS day,
       SUM(CASE WHEN N.day = D.day THEN N.net ELSE 0 END) AS net,
       AVG(N.net) AS avg
FROM dates D
LEFT JOIN (SELECT day, SUM(sales) AS net
           FROM file F
           GROUP BY day) N
ON N.day <= D.day
GROUP BY D.day
ORDER BY day DESC
```

It works by finding the net sale for each day in the file table,
then selecting the day, the sum for that day, and the average of non-null values up to that day, after joining to the dates table.

To test it: See this SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7271/3/0

Comment: Neat and classy. Thank you very much.